# Get number of free connections in connection pool

Tags: java, spring, connection-pooling, apache-commons-dbcp

In my project Spring manages connection pool with org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource class. Is possible to get how many connections are free or used in current time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the javadocs, you should be able to read this from the [getNumIdle()](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/api-1.2.2/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.html#getNumIdle%28%29) and [getNumActive()](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/api-1.2.2/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.html#getNumActive%28%29) methods, if you can get an instance of the BasicDataSource.

Answer (score 0):

To get an instance of BasicDataSource you can use JMX and access the exposed beans. For example you can use [Java Visual VM](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/index.html) which is bundled with JDK since version 6, update 7. Of course you must install the [MBeans plugin](http://java.net/projects/visualvm/content/mbeans_tab.html).